# Как соединить две таблицы в бд?

Tags: база-данных, php

Задача такова: есть таблица пользователя (`members`) и таблица юнита (`unit`), в таблице пользователя есть столбик `unit`, как в этот столбик занести юнита, например, с ид 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Структура:

- members - `id,(some fields),unit_id`
- unit - `id,(some fields).`

Можно и нужно связать `unit_id` и `id` из `members`. При вставке - сначала делать insert в `unit`, затем в members подставлять `id` `unit`. Получить `id` `Unit` можно сл. образом: через php+mysql вытащить его через ф-ю `mysql_insert_id`, либо уже при вставке в `members` воспользоваться функцией mysql

```
LAST_INSERT_ID(): INSERT into `members` VALUES (some fields, LAST_INSERT_ID())
```

Это общая идея, когда-то делал так, почитайте, как использовать эти функции и все поймете, если нет - пишите, будем код педалить. :)

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из принципа работ с базами данных, поле unit в таблице members должно хранить лишь id юнита. По этому id в таблице units ты выбираешь из базы нужный тебе юнит.

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял то примерно так:

```
INSERT INTO table (SELECT * FROM another_table WHERE id="your_id");
```

Comment: Зачем делать дополнительный запрос, чтоб узнать your_id. Как я понимаю, у него идет сразу 2 запроса на вставку в базу. Сначала в unit, потом в members. Вот мы и вставляем - INSERT INTO `unit` VALUES(val1,val2,..). Второй запрос идет сразу после первого - INSERT into `members` VALUES(val1,val2,LAST_INSERT_ID(),...); И все. В Mysql уже есть много своих функций, позволяющих получить данные без участия php)